# discontinous axis in subplot - python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I would like to have plot with an y axis that is devided into two parts. The lower part should have a normal scale while the upper one should scale with a factor of 10.

I already found some examples on how to make plots with broken x or y axes, for example:
http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/broken_axis.html

But I do not understand how to achieve this, when I want to apply this to one single subplot inside a 2x2 grid of plots. If it is important, I set up the plots like this:

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_size_inches(8, 6)

fig.add_subplot(221)
[...]
fig.add_subplot(222)
[...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [use gridspec](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html) to layout the shape and location of the axes:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(4, 2)
ax00 = plt.subplot(gs[:2, 0])
ax01 = plt.subplot(gs[:2, 1])
ax10a = plt.subplot(gs[2, 0])
ax10b = plt.subplot(gs[3, 0])
ax11 = plt.subplot(gs[2:, 1])

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 500)
y = 100*np.cos(10*x)**2*np.exp(-x**2)
for ax in (ax00, ax01, ax10a, ax10b, ax11):
    ax.plot(x, y)

ax10a.set_ylim(60, 110)
ax10b.set_ylim(0, 10) 

ax10a.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax10b.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax10a.xaxis.tick_top()
ax10a.tick_params(labeltop='off') # don't put tick labels at the top
ax10b.xaxis.tick_bottom()

d = .015 # how big to make the diagonal lines in axes coordinates
# arguments to pass plot, just so we don't keep repeating them
kwargs = dict(transform=ax10a.transAxes, color='k', clip_on=False)
ax10a.plot((-d,+d),(-d,+d), **kwargs)      # top-left diagonal
ax10a.plot((1-d,1+d),(-d,+d), **kwargs)    # top-right diagonal

kwargs.update(transform=ax10b.transAxes)  # switch to the bottom axes
ax10b.plot((-d,+d),(1-d,1+d), **kwargs)   # bottom-left diagonal
ax10b.plot((1-d,1+d),(1-d,1+d), **kwargs) # bottom-right diagonal

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Ok thank you so far, it works nearly as supposed. But I have some problem with the axes labels:
The y-labels are fine, but i would like to have the label centred at the discontinuous axis. How to do this?
And for some reason, the upper row (there my discontinuous plot is placed) does not show the x-labels. The "set_xlabel()" seems to be ignored.

Comment: Those are good questions, but unfortunately I don't know the answers off hand. (The y-label *could* be centered with a call to plt.text but that seems like a dirty solution to me...) Please ask in a new question.

Comment: You might just be forced to manually place a label if you can't think of a better solution

Comment: The solution I found was:
Use a 2x2 gridspec and insert gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(2,1) for the discontinuous axis plot.
The hidden x-labels were caused by too less space between the plots.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you set up a 4x4 grid of axes, and have 3 of the axes span 2x2 of that space? Then the plot you want to have broken axes on can just cover the remaining 2x2 space as parts `ax4_upper` and `ax4_lower`.

```
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((4, 4), (0, 0), colspan=2, rowspan=2)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((4, 4), (0, 2), colspan=2, rowspan=2)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((4, 4), (2, 0), colspan=2, rowspan=2)
ax4_upper = plt.subplot2grid((4, 4), (2, 2), colspan=2, rowspan=1)
ax4_lower = plt.subplot2grid((4, 4), (3, 2), colspan=2, rowspan=1)
```

You can then set the `ylim` values for `ax4_upper` and `ax4_lower`, and continue as your example showed:

```
# hide the spines between ax4 upper and lower
ax4_upper.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax4_lower.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax4_upper.xaxis.tick_top()
ax4_upper.tick_params(labeltop='off') # don't put tick labels at the top
ax4_lower.xaxis.tick_bottom()

d = .015 # how big to make the diagonal lines in axes coordinates
# arguments to pass plot, just so we don't keep repeating them
kwargs = dict(transform=ax4_upper.transAxes, color='k', clip_on=False)
ax4_upper.plot((-d,+d),(-d,+d), **kwargs)      # top-left diagonal
ax4_upper.plot((1-d,1+d),(-d,+d), **kwargs)    # top-right diagonal

kwargs.update(transform=ax4_lower.transAxes)  # switch to the bottom axes
ax4_lower.plot((-d,+d),(1-d,1+d), **kwargs)   # bottom-left diagonal
ax4_lower.plot((1-d,1+d),(1-d,1+d), **kwargs) # bottom-right diagonal

plt.show()
```

[image: 2x2 with broken axes]